# what ES should i use for a multilevel meta-analysis (metafor package) of pre-post studies with intervention and control group?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, effect-size, metafor

We've done a systematic review of studies that investigate the effect of physical exercise on pain and disability in workers, and we've been asked to complement it with a meta-analysis of the data.

So, we selected the studies that featured an intervention and a control group, and reported pre and post intervention measures.

the variables we have are:

```
me_pre_int
sd_pre_int
me_post_int
sd_post_int
num_int

me_pre_c
sd_pre_c
me_post_c
sd_post_c
num_c
```

so, mean, sd, and sample size for both intervention/experimental group and control group.

What measure of ES should i use for the meta-analysis? We have different measurements on different scales for pain, so we probably need a standardized mean difference, but i'm not sure what to use.

should i just compare the post intervention data between experimental and control group?

Or do i need to compute change scores for both intervention and control groups, and then compare the two?

I'm using the metafor package, so it basically boils down to what data should i enter in the escalc() function.

I'd be happy to provide more details if necessary.

I know one of the options for escalc is to calculate mean change score, but it requires the correlation of data, which i don't have for any study.

also, the sd of pre-post differences were not reported.